# Extract all tags from a Google Document using a lazy regex

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google Docs document containing the line `<dear> <person>`, and I want FindText to return one tag at a time. I use this line:

```
Logger.log(body.findText("<.*?>").getElement().getText());
```

And it logs `<dear> <person>` instead of just `<dear>`. 
I guess that for some reason the matching is not working in "lazy" mode, but I ran it on https://regex101.com and it shows the two tags as two different matches.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Then use `<[^><]*>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with lazyness; your regex **is** lazy. The method [`findText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findText(String)) returns a [`RangeElement`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element), which has information about  the start and end of a match. The problem is that you call `getElement` on that, which returns the entire element containing the match. So the result is the entire paragraph (or another element) that contained the matching text.

To correctly extract matching text, use `isPartial` to check if the match is only a part of the element; if so, take the start and end positions and slice the text as shown below.

```
function search() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var pattern = "<.*?>";
  var found = body.findText(pattern);
  while (found) {
    var text = found.getElement().getText();
    if (found.isPartial()) {
      var start = found.getStartOffset();
      var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
      text = text.slice(start, end+1);
    }
    Logger.log(text);
    found = body.findText(pattern, found);
  }
}
```

Notes:

- In Apps Script the end offset is inclusive; in `String.slice` method it is not. This is the reason for `end+1` in `slice`.
- The loop is necessary to return all results. `findText` only finds one match, called `found` here. Then this match is passed to `findText` as its second parameter, so that it finds *next* match.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much. The documentation wasn't super clear about what is returned exactly so I guessed it was one result per element. I don't have enough reputation to upvote. Thanks.